# CDBurner XP does not recognize HL-DT-ST BD-RE BH10LS30 Blu-Ray burner

Tags: windows, burning, blu-ray

I've got an LG `HL-DT-ST BD-RE BH10LS30` Blu-Ray burner and want to use it with CDBurner XP on Windows 7. Unfortunately it does not like this device. It says **"No compatible devices"** in its drive list. Other programs like **Nero or Windows' built-in burning work** like a charm. At the CDBurner XP [compatibility list](http://chaski.cdburnerxp.se/en/testeddrives?search=BH10LS30) it is listed, which I find kind of odd.

I called LG's customer service for Germany and asked about that incompatibility and about firmware updates. The guy at the phone however was pretty much useless. He told me to download and buy Nero or use Windows' built-in burning capabilities. He further told me that there is a so-called [LG Autoupdated](http://www.lg.com/de/support/product/support-product-profile.jsp?customerModelCode=BH10LS30&initialTab=drivers&targetPage=support-product-profile&searchEngineModelCode=BH10LS30) *(broken)* or `LG Tool Kit` which I have to install so the device can update itself.

This very unintuitive piece of software **did make a firmware update**, so I am now at version 1.01. It shows it like this:

> Firmware Version : 1.01
>   Content : -PRODISC BD-R SL 4x support -CMC
>   BD-R DL 6x support -TAIYO YUDEN BD-R SL LTH 6x support -MKM BD-R SL
>   LTH 4x, 6x write quality improvement -New BCA BD disc support

This is all great, but **CDBurner XP still does not recognize it**. Do you know of a solution? Or do yoou know another burning program that is not Nero and does the same stuff for free?

---

**Edit:** After more updates it is still not working.